# Как при парсинге отображать только новые посты?

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужен парсер, который сообщит о всех новых постах на сайте, но только если ранее они не отображались. Например, пользователь запускает парсер после долгой паузы, во время которой на сайте вышло несколько новостей и просто отображает их текст, пропуская старые посты.

Так понимаю, что для этого нужно вести какой-либо текстовый документ с датами этих постов или что-то в этом роде.

Сейчас мой код выглядит так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.debian.org/News/'

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('body')

date = table.find('tt').text.strip()

with open('date.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(date)
```

Что нужно добавить, чтобы получить задуманное?

***UDP*** Выложу готовый код, может быть пригодится кому...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.debian.org/News/'

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('body')

date = table.find_all('tt')
news = table.find_all('strong')

old_date = open("date.txt", "r").read().splitlines()[0]

for d,n in zip(date,news):
    dd = d.text.strip()
    nn = n.text.strip()
    if dd == old_date:
        break
    print(dd,nn)

old_date = open('date.txt', 'w')
old_date.write(date[0].text.strip())
```

Comment: NameError: name 'news' is not defined. Приведите код, которым вы собственно парсите текст, иначе непонятно, как тут подсказывать.

Comment: вы же в date.txt будете писАть дату новостей? тогда при очередном парсинге сравните даты и допишите новые, и их же (новые) отдайте пользователю

Comment: @CrazyElf, Сейчас мне хватит и вывода заголовка новости. Для этого вместо date = table.find('tt').text.strip() использую news = table.find('strong').text.strip()

Comment: @Jack_oS, другого способа не придумал. На словах просто, но слабо представляю, как это написать. Не покажешь как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно заготовка будет выглядеть так:

```
old_date = '[09 May 2020]' # эту дату надо читать из файла

date = table.find_all('tt')
news = table.find_all('strong')

for d,n in zip(date,news):
    dd = d.text.strip()
    nn = n.text.strip()
    if dd == old_date:
        break
    print(dd,nn)

old_date = date[0].text.strip() # а тут обратно в файл записать
```